# Animação no CSS ativar de X em X tempo

Tags: css, animação, css-animations

Existe algum parâmetro pra minha animação ativar de x em x tempo?

Por exemplo, a cada 7 segundos quero que essa animação ative:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 body {
     display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
 .btn-buy {
     box-shadow: none;
        border: none;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width: 30%;
        background-color: #68dc32;
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: 600;
        cursor: pointer;
        animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: buyScale;
        animation-iteration-count: 2;
    }
    
    @keyframes buyScale {
        0%{transform: scale(1);}
        50%{transform: scale(1.1);}
        100%{transform: scale(1)}
    }
    
    
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="btn-buy">Comprar</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Existe algum parâmetro no animation sem ter que fazer isso por JS?

Comment: No seu caso deixe a animação como `infinit` e com o tempo de 8s, sendo que de 0% a 12,5% ( 100/8 = 12,5) a animação tem que acontecer por completo, (a animação toda acontece no primeiro dos 8 segundos) e de 12,5% a 100% ela fica com os valores inicias de antes da animação, ou seja scale(1), por 7 segundo antes de reiniciar.

Comment: @hugocsl Mas esse "tempo de 8s" que você diz, é o animation duration? Porque se for, fica bem lento quando está "animando"...

Comment: O `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` é infinito. O `animation-duration: 8s;` eu sugeri 8s, mas a animação mesmo vai acontecer em 1s, os outros 7s fica parado, com o mesmo estado do inicial. Se vc quiser vc pode ajustar esses valores ao seu gosto, é matemática simples... Quer que aconteça em 0.5s faz sua animação acontecer de 0% a 6,25% de de 6,25% a 100% fica parado, vai ficar parado por 7,5 segundos antes de iniciar novamente a animação. Leia Duplicada que tem mais detalhes e exemplos

Comment: @hugocsl eu entendi, consegui reproduzir em partes, o problema é esse aqui, vamos por de exemplo a animação com 8s, de 0 a 12,5 ele vai normal com o scale(1.1) beleza, fica lento apenas no processo de 12,5 a 100, que ele vai voltar ao "estado normal", pra scale(1). Vou dar uma calculada melhor aqui pra ver se consigo reproduzir, eu entendi o lance da regra de 3.

Comment: Como falei de 0 a 12,5 tem que acontecer "Toda" a animação, ou seja, de 0 a 6,25 vai para 1.1, e de 6,25 a 12,5 volta para 1. E assim fica scale(1) de 12,5 até 100%

Comment: @hugocsl consegui, ficou bom. Se quiser por como resposta eu marco como aceito!

Comment: A pergunta continua como duplicada entende..., se quiser me dar uma força da um Up na outra Resposta que marquei como duplicada ;) 